# In MVC type.GetProperties().ElementAt(1).CustomAttributes returning 0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, modelattribute

In MVC 4, I have created a ADO.NET Entity Data Model (using Database First Approach) and then added a class in the project to add custom attributes like **DisplayAttribute** or **DataTypeAttribute**.

**Example :-**

```
[MetadataType(typeof(UploadFilesMetaData))]
//UploadFiles is the class defined in my Model Object
public partial class UploadFiles
{
}

//MetaData class to add attributes
public partial class UploadFilesMetaData
{
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Document Name is required field.")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "Document Name")]
    public string DocumentName_vch { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "Document Description")]
    public string DocumentDescription_vch { get; set; }
}
```

And My requirement is to read these attributes at runtime.

But the issue is that the code "*type.GetProperties().ElementAt(1).CustomAttributes*" returning 0.

**

***Above mentioned code returning expected result***

** If i add attributes to my model class like UploadFiles. But the problem with this approach is that attribute code got overwritten whenever i update model from database.

Please help....

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting file on your controller/API controller. From the question , what you actually want is not clear !! Why should you change the entity model object. It is highly recommended to write custom class on other locations but not on model generated by ADO.NET.

Comment: Hello Aneesh, First of all my question have nothing to do with files. And Yes you are right, it is highly recommendable to write separate custom class rather then modifying Model Classes and i am doing the same by using the concept of Partial & MetaData class(example mentioned in the question). And now my problem/requirement is to pick the attributes at runtime which are defined over properties via MetaData Class.